# How to retrieve Ressource URL in Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin7

I need to retrieve the url of used ressources in my vaadin 7 web application, here is an example :

I used this logo in my page :

```
    Resource res = new ThemeResource("img/logo.png");
    Image image = new Image(null, res);
```

After inspecting the image with Firebug here's the url i get :

```
    <img class="v-image v-widget" src="http://localhost:8082/WApplication/VAADIN/themes/UITheme/img/logo.png" alt="">
```

So how to get the url of a deployed ressources in vaadin 7 web application.

(`http://localhost:8082/WApplication/VAADIN/themes/UITheme/img/logo.png`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to build this path:

```
String absPath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String path = absPath + "/VAADIN/themes/UITheme/img/logo.png"
```

the name of current theme can also be retrieved to not hardcode it

```
VaadinService.getCurrent().getConfiguredTheme(VaadinService.getCurrentRequest());
```

I suggest playing with other methods of VaadinService, so maybe something is better for your needs.